# combating roundoff error in Qt (QPainter)?

Tags: c++, qt, qpainter, candlestick-chart

I'm drawing a simple candlestick chart with the following formula determining candlestick centers:

```
x = width() + i * scale * (candle_width + candle_spacing)
```

The multiplication with `i` is a source of roundoff errors, as you can see in the image, the greater `|i|`, the more the roundoff error is amplified . The center of the candlestick wobbles around. I've tried to use antialiasing, but it only makes the image worse. It is especially apparent when dragging the candlestick chart around (extra feature). I am using `qreal` (`double`) for all calculations, except for `i`, that is of type `int`, obviously.

[image: Snapshot]

Part of image zoomed (8x) to show issue:

[image: Part of Snapshot (8x Zoom)]

Comment: Show more context. The types of the variables are important here. Try for a [mcve].

Comment: Please point out, highlight and explain in more detail how the problem manifests. Can you compare the result you get to a manually created one which shows what you want? Choose tailored data to make it visible with fewer data, maybe 5. If necessary show a cutout of higher indexes, if the problem is not visible in 5.

Comment: @Yunnosch I did mention I use qreal and my distro uses double as a qreal alias. You can't see off-centre candles in the image?

Comment: @Yunnosch I can't provide meaningful code, as I'm using my own fixed-point library. The data are from a real price chart. Drawing a candlestick chart isn't rocket-science either, the problem is obvious.

Comment: Without knowing details, it looks like you convert `double` (or `qreal`) to `int` after computing left side and right side (or width) of candles. May be, it's better to convert candle center to `int` and then determine left and right (or width) using `int` arithmetic only.

Comment: @Scheff No, I provide `qreal`s to `drawRect()` directly, hoping for the best, but I've often seen in Qt's source code, that it rounds coodinates/widths/heights internally.

Comment: So, you let `drawRect()` do this. May be, the better solution is to use `drawRect()` with `int` (or `QPoint`) so that you don't lose control about precision/rounding. (You can apply any transformation (which is applied inside of `QPainter`) on your own as well.)

Comment: Please, keep in mind: Finally, you got pixel coordinates which are `int` values. The `QPainter`s API with `qreal` and such is good if there are transformations set (for translation, scaling, etc.). But anyhow, after last transformation into "screen space" it must be adjusted to view pos and size which is `int`egral by nature.

Comment: Have you tried to simply draw the thick candle parts with thick lines (i.e. change the line width) instead of using `drawRect()`?

Comment: @Scheff I solved the problem, the solution was to circumvent the internal Qt's rounding and go with integer coordinates, widths, heights. I don't think a set `QTransform` would do it, as you lose control at what's happening that way. Write answer, I'll accept.

Comment: @Scheff you can see many "wobbly" commercial candlestick charts, that's why I think using a `QTransform` wouldn't cut it.

Comment: May be, you got me wrong. I meant it the opposite way: Doing all the transformations in your code, convert floating point coordinates to `int`, and then determine coordinates and width for `drawRect()` in `int`. Transformations in `QPainter` have to be reset for this, of course.

Comment: Concerning the _many "wobbly" commercial candlestick charts_: Isn't it very satisfying to beat them? ;-) (...considering that it's actually not that hard.)

Comment: Not really, the most important thing with price charts is direction (up or down) and you can see direction from "wobbly" charts just fine, beauty isn't terribly important.

Comment: Btw. I checked `drawLine()` with line width. It shows similar rounding issues like `drawRect()` with `qreal`s. So, I don't see any better way than that you are using now.

Comment: @Scheff Yeah, I remember from memory looking at that code. I thought it would be something incomprehensible to me and then I saw the `qRound()`s. Next thing you know, you'll be trading stocks, the chart is from the German DAX index.

Answer (score 1):

The solution was to circumvent Qt's internal rounding of coordinates/widths/heights and do it yourself. What I did was to round the center point `x` myself, then I check whether the rounded candle width is odd/even. If it is even, I will add 1 to make it odd. This is to make the center line always centered within a candle. Here's the fixed image and some code:

```
auto const x(qRound(transform(i)));
auto rounded_candle_width(qRound(scaled_candle_width));
rounded_candle_width += !(rounded_candle_width % 2);
```

[image]